# Задеплоить WAR На Jetty. Нет связи пути запроса с сервлетом

Tags: java, servlet, jetty

Хочу разобраться в том, как деплоить `WAR`-файлы на Jetty. Я написал такой контроллер:

```
package controller;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet(name = "HomeController", urlPatterns = {"/home"})
public class HomeController extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                      HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.getWriter().println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

`web.xml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

`pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>aoizora</groupId>
  <artifactId>aoizora</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>aoizora Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
      </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>aoizora</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.20.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

После сборки проекта я получил файл `aoizora.war`. Скопировал его в директорию, где стоит джетти, в webapps/aoizora. Но при обращении по адресам `localhost:8080/aoizora/home` или `localhost:8080/home` сервлет не возвращает строку `Hello, WOrld`. Почему так происходит? Я ведь определил в аннотации,с каким путем контейнер сервлетов должен связать данный контроллер.

Comment: нужно перезапустить jetty, чтобы он запустил добавленный war

Comment: @keekkenen, нет, это не помогает. Запросы на /home все равно возвращают 404. К тому же джетти постоянно мониторит директорию webapps. При добавлении нового war перезапускать сервер не надо.